# Sort a 2D array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm currently reading in a list of words from a file and trying to sort them line by line. 
I can read each line in and print the words out just fine, but I can't seem to sort each line individually. The first line is sorted, but the second is not. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
    int fd;
    int n_char = 0;
    int charCount = 0, wordCount = 0, lineCount = 0;
    int wordsPerLine[100];

    char buffer;
    char words[6][9];

    fd = open(inputfile, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    wordsPerLine[0] = 0;

    /* use the read system call to obtain 10 characters from fd */
    while( (n_char = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(char))) != 0) {

        if (buffer == '\n' || buffer == ' ') {
            words[wordCount][charCount] = '\0';
            charCount = 0;
            wordCount++;
            wordsPerLine[lineCount] += 1;
            if (buffer == '\n') {
                lineCount++;
                wordsPerLine[lineCount] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            words[wordCount][charCount++] = buffer;
        }
    }

    printf("Num Words: %d  ---  Num Lines: %d\n", wordCount, lineCount);

    char tmp[9];

    int m, n;
    int i, x, totalCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < wordsPerLine[i]; x++) {

            /* iterate through each word 'm' in line 'i' */
            for(m = 0; m < wordsPerLine[i]; m++) {
                for(n = 0; n < wordsPerLine[i]; n++) {
                    if(strcmp(words[n-1], words[n])>0) {
                        strcpy(tmp, words[n-1]);
                        strcpy(words[n-1], words[n]);
                        strcpy(words[n], tmp);
                    }
                }
            } /* end sorting */

        }
    }

    printf("Sorted:\n");
    totalCount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        printf("Line %d (%d words)\n", i + 1, wordsPerLine[i]);
        for(x = 0; x < wordsPerLine[i]; x++) {
            printf("%s\n", words[totalCount++]);
        }
    }
```

My sample input file is:

```
great day out
foo bar food
```

Comment: And your expectet output is? "day great out" and "bar foo food"?

Comment: and what are you currently getting?

Comment: I am getting "day great out" and "foo bar food". It should be "day great out" and "bar foo food"

Comment: It is possible that the trouble is you don't null terminate your data if the last line of input does not end with a newline.  OTOH, it is fairly unlikely that the input file does not end with a newline.

Comment: You have to index the words of the `n`th line with the sum of `wordsPerLine` of all previous lines. I guess you sort the first line twice, because you always start counting the words from 0, whereas you should start counting from 3 in the second line. (You account for that with `totalCount` when you print the words, but not when you sort them.)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't access `words[n - 1]` when `n` starts at 0. Start the inner loop with `1`, or better yet with `m + 1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's go by small parts...

To see if the problem is in the reading, comment the reading part and try to add:

```
 char words[][9] = {"great", "day", "out", "foo", "bar", "food"};
```

and set the counters to the value they would with this input also...

Your loop is accessing some data out of the bounds... I would recommend you to try your sorting code with an array of numbers first and see if it is sorting them correctly...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 6
int main()
{
   char words[][9] = {"great", "day", "out", "foo", "bar", "food"};
   int numbers[] = {20, 10, 50, 5, 30, -50};
   int i, j, temp;

   for(i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
      for(j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
          if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
          {
             temp = numbers[j];
             numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
             numbers[j + 1] = temp;
          }


    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
        //printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
}
```

Note also that this is the least efficient implementation of bubble sort (but is the same you provided), you can improve it by adding a variable to check in the inner loop some change happened for instance(which would mean that it is already sorted and you can stop sorting)...

Also, after each iteration on the outter loop one element is going to be placed in its final place (try to find out which one), which means that you won't need to consider this element in the next iteration, so after each iteration in the outer loop the number of elements compared in the inner loop can be reduced by 1...

you can find more info about bubble sort [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* iterate through each line */
for (i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) { 

    /* iterate through each word 'm' in line 'i' */
    for(m = 0; m < wordsPerLine[i]; m++) {
        for(n = m+1; n < wordsPerLine[i]; n++) {
            if(strcmp(words[n + totalCount], words[m + totalCount]) < 0) {
                strcpy(tmp, words[m + totalCount]);
                strcpy(words[m + totalCount], words[n + totalCount]);
                strcpy(words[n + totalCount], tmp);
            }
        }
    } /* end sorting */  
    totalCount += wordsPerLine[i];
}
```

I just needed to keep a running count of each word per line, so i know what line to start comparing with